# reading videos using cordova-plugin-media-streaming close the window automatically

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I'm working on an ionic mobile application where I needed to read videos on streaming by providing the URI of the video online. So I used `cordova-plugin-media-streaming`plugin offered by cordova.

My problem is that: the window reading the video closes automatically after the video finishes, the user won't be able to play the video again in this window.

In the official documentation of the plugin [that i found [here](https://github.com/nchutchind/cordova-plugin-streaming-media)], there is an attribute called `shouldAutoClose`that should be set to false to avoid that problem. But this didn't work for me.

Here is the code I used to play a video on streaming :

```
     startVideo(item : Multimediasendtrust) {

     let options = {

      successCallback: () => { console.log('Finished Video') },
      errorCallback: (e) => { console.log('Error: ', e) },
      orientation: 'portrait',
      controls: true,
      shouldAutoClose:  false

    };

    console.log('those are option ',options );

    console.log('the link of the video ', item.url_media);

    this.streamingMedia.playVideo(item.url_media, options);   }
```

Can anyone help please. Thanks in advance.